# How can I put a bean object to sessionMap, and then retrieve its properties on jsp page using Struts 2 property tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, valuestack

In login `Action` I am checking user authentication, and if it is validated, I am putting the user bean into `sessionMap`:

```java
public String execute()
{
    if(userValid)  
        sessionMap.put("userBean", userBean); //userBean retrieved from DB
}
```

Now on the landing jsp, when trying to retrieve the session items:

```jsp
<s:property value="#session.userBean.name" />
```

Obviously this would return an `Object` type, as I am storing it that way, so how can I type caste this to `UserBean` class.

I was expecting to get a solution for this on Google, but found it nowhere since this seems to be a basic implementation. So please let me know if there is any other way to implement this functionality using Struts2.

Comment: What makes you think you need to cast anything?

Comment: the userBean gets stored as Object type in the sessionMap, how will I retrieve userBean.name if userBean at the time of retrieval will be of Object type.

Comment: Anyway, if you can suggest any other way to do this, you are most welcome.
Thanks

Comment: How about `#session.userBean.name`? OGNL is an expression language; you essentially never need to cast anything to anything.

Comment: I don't know how this is happening, but as you can see what you have suggested me just now, I have already mentioned the same in the question. I tried this again and it worked this time. 

Anyway, thanks for the solution.

Is this the right way of implementing this functionality??

Comment: It's the only reasonable way to do it; it's what expression languages are for.

Comment: Agree, though in (rare) cases it could be preferable doing it in an action method (sort of a getter), eg. if your key is dynamic and you don't want to get your JSP dirty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you can't cast it to `UserBean` class if the object is not the instance of that class. In the value attribute you have put a string `"#session.userBean.name"`. Struts parse this string for OGNL expression and if it's a valid expression that returns a value, it will replace it with that value. The returned type is `Object`, but this type is determined by `ValueStack` implementation.

Then property tag writes this object to the `out`. It uses `toString()` to convert the object to string. And if your object implements this method, then this value would be written.

Looks like your expression returns an `Object`, which has instance type `String`, so it's already implemented this method.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me...

```
<sp:property value="#session.usertype"/>
<sp:property value="#session.bean.loginID"/>
```

This both worked fine for me...

```
sessionMap.put("bean", loginBean);
sessionMap.put("usertype", loginBean.getUserType());
```

I declared something like this....

Just make sure that in `property` tag you you same name you used while setting the bean in `sessionMap` ....

This should probably work....